# Continue processing of WPF application when not active window

Tags: wpf

I am new to windows coding in general, so please excuse my (probably incorrect) use of terminology.

I am writing a WPF application that allows you to control a virtual joystick, using the vJoystick SDK.

I have the code basically working, but when I switch to another application (eg previewing the virtual controller in windows game controllers), it stops working while it is not the active window.

I have looked at "Workers" in WPF, but this seems to be for something else (Keeping your UI responsive while it is doing some calculations)

Could someone point me in the right direction for making a WPF app (Or portion of) continue running while the window is not the active one?

TIA

Comment: The WPF application is probably still running, but not responding to events. In order to do this, if I understand your query, you need to look at global hooks (either mouse hooks or keyboard hooks, depending on what you need). Good luck & happy coding!

Comment: I am not using Hooks, it would be RawInput.  
Hooks cannot tell WHICH device the data is coming from (ie cannot distinguish one mouse from another)